# FireDac multithread (Conexões simultâneas - Servidor REST) DELPHI

Tags: delphi, multithreading, conexão, datasnap, firedac

**Bom dia Pessoal,**

Gostaria de solicitar uma ajuda de vocês, caso alguém puder ajudar fico super agradecido.

A dúvida seria razoavelmente simples, **como trabalhar com Multi Thread no FireDac?**
Em outros bancos de dados, como por exemplo o DBISAM, possui um componente para Sessões, basta configurar esse componente e tudo se resolve, porém o firedac não possui este componente.

**Explicando melhor o caso:**

Desenvolvi um Servidor REST em Delphi utilizando DataSnap para exportar dados de uma base de dados (Firebird) para dispositivos mobile.

A conexão com o banco de dados é feita pelos componentes FireDac. Quando inicio o servidor faço a conexão com o banco de dados, a conexão fica estabelecida até o servidor ser fechado.

Realizando alguns testes percebi que, quando um dispositivo realiza as requisições tudo funciona perfeitamente, porém **o problema surge quando vários dispositivos fazem conexões simultâneas**, ocorre diversos erros, Access Violation e erros do banco de dados.

Para corrigir esses erros, em cada método requisitado no servidor inicio uma nova conexão com o banco de dados. Fazendo isto os erros não ocorrem mais e posso conectar diversos dispositivos simultaneamente. 
Sei que essa não é a maneira correta, percebi logo de inicio que o processo ficou MUITO lento, pelo fato de toda requisição iniciar uma nova conexão.

**Então gostaria de saber como faço para trabalhar com sessões no FireDac, para cada requisição no servidor não influenciar em outras conexões.**

Grato desde já.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Bom dia a todos,
Somente para informa-los, resolvi o problema utilizando Pool Connection. Funcionou perfeitamente. Caso algo precisar de uma ajuda é só dar um toque.

Comment: amigo, poste uma resposta genérica, é difícil para pessoas que acessam o site sem conta tirarem suas dúvidas quando você pede que contate para tirar a dúvida.

Comment: Olá, é possível postar como você utilizou o pool connection?

Comment: Olá por favor post um exemplo do código para podermos nos localizar

Answer (score 1):

Para você trabalhar com sessões no DataSnap, tens que criar o seu projeto a partir do `DataSnap Server`, pois a tecnologia `REST` por padrão trabalha com `LifeCycle` **Invocation**, a cada execução de um server method uma instância da classe é criada e depois destruída, por esse motivo que a tecnologia `REST` não vai adiantar.

Criando o seu projeto pelo `DataSnap Server`, tens a opção de `LifeCycle` **Session**, e essa tecnologia vai atender o que você precisa, quando o cliente conecta o servidor mantém uma instância da classe por sessão do DataSnap.

Com o projeto criado, na classe `ServerContainer1`, tem o componente `DSServerClass` que é responsável pelo ciclo de dados, na propriedade `LifeCycle` mudar para **Session**.

Espero ter esclarecido sua dúvida. Qualquer coisa da um berro.